# Is there a loop to mutate a new column based on existing multiple ascending columns with ascending values?

Tags: tidyverse

My dataset looks something like this:

```
med_1_atc    med_2_atc   med_3_atc   
N06AX07      N06AX07     N06AX07        
N06AX07               
N06AX09      N06AX07     N06AG07        
N06AD07               
M06AX07              
D06FX07              
L06TX07      N06AX07     N06AX07
```

I want to create a new variable `med_use` that tags as `1` if any variable ending with `_atc` has a code that starts with `NO6A`.

Should look something like this:

```
med_1_atc    med_2_atc   med_3_atc    med_use   
N06AX07      N06AX07     N06AX07         1        
N06AX07                                  1
N06AX09      N06AX07     N02BE07         1       
N06AD07                                  1              
M06AX07              
D06FX07              
L06TX07                  N06AX07         1
```

I have used the following code:

```
df <- mutate (df, 
            med_use = case_when(
                      ends_with("_atc", "N06A") ~ 1
                        TRUE ~ NA_real_
              ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use `dplyr::rowwise` and `dplyr::c_across`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(med_use = as.numeric(any(grepl("^N06A", c_across(ends_with("_atc"))))),
         med_use = ifelse(med_use, med_use, NA_real_)) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#>   med_1_atc med_2_atc med_3_atc med_use
#>   <chr>     <chr>     <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1 N06AX07   N06AX07   N06AX07         1
#> 2 N06AX07   <NA>      <NA>            1
#> 3 N06AX09   N06AX07   N06AG07         1
#> 4 N06AD07   <NA>      <NA>            1
#> 5 M06AX07   <NA>      <NA>           NA
#> 6 D06FX07   <NA>      <NA>           NA
#> 7 L06TX07   N06AX07   N06AX07         1
```

A second option would be to use `rowSums` with `dplyr::across`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(med_use = rowSums(across(ends_with("_atc"), ~ grepl("^N06A", .x))),
         med_use = ifelse(med_use, 1, NA_real_))
#>   med_1_atc med_2_atc med_3_atc med_use
#> 1   N06AX07   N06AX07   N06AX07       1
#> 2   N06AX07      <NA>      <NA>       1
#> 3   N06AX09   N06AX07   N06AG07       1
#> 4   N06AD07      <NA>      <NA>       1
#> 5   M06AX07      <NA>      <NA>      NA
#> 6   D06FX07      <NA>      <NA>      NA
#> 7   L06TX07   N06AX07   N06AX07       1
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(med_1_atc = c(
  "N06AX07", "N06AX07", "N06AX09",
  "N06AD07", "M06AX07", "D06FX07", "L06TX07"
), med_2_atc = c(
  "N06AX07",
  NA, "N06AX07", NA, NA, NA, "N06AX07"
), med_3_atc = c(
  "N06AX07",
  NA, "N06AG07", NA, NA, NA, "N06AX07"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -7L
))
```